# R call java with Chinese coding garbled

Tags: java, r, encoding

Issues about Chinese coding garbled in R.
I called java function in R with the String type of return values,but I print them in R with unidentifiable codes.
for example
I defined a variable `names` in java class `Hello` like this below.

---

```
public String name2 = new String("苹果".getBytes(),"UTF-8");
```

or

```
public String names = "苹果";
```

---

I called it in R like this.

---

```
library(rJava)
.jinit(...)
.jaddClassPath(...)
Hello = J("Hello")
he = new(Hello)
name = he$names2

print(name2)
```

---

when I define the string as `utf-8` unicode,it prints `苹锟斤拷`,I have no ideas about how to solve it...

appreciate any help.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This should work

```
iconv(he$names,'UTF-8','UTF-8')
```

Comment: thanks.
the first definition can not show correctly,the second definition is right.